# Run multiple azure function projects on same solution

Tags: visual-studio, azure-functions

I am trying to run multiple azure projects localhost on same solution but getting issue for dependency injection because it overwrites "startup.cs"
for example.

```
Solution
  FunctionApp1 --> startup.cs
  FunctionApp2 --> startup.cs
```

But when it executes FunctionApp2 is using startup.cs from FunctionApp1.

Comment: can you please show us a screenshot of your project, and the details of the startup.cs?

Comment: Hello, if the answer is helpful, could you please accept it as answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there might be some incorrect settings in your function app. Possible reasons are as below:

1.In the `Startup.cs`, check if you're calling the correct `Startup` method in `[assembly:xxx]`. For example, in `FunctionApp2`(suppose the namespace is also `FunctionApp2`) -> `Startup.cs`, you're using FunctionApp1's Startup method in [assembly:xxx], like `[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(FunctionApp1.Startup))]`. This may happen when you reference the project `FunctionApp1` in `FunctionApp2`.

2.Or this might be a temp issue. You can create a new solution, and create 2 new function apps, this may resolve the issue.

3.Or you're using some old packages. Please use the latest packages for your functions.

And I think the reason 1 may be the root cause. Please let me know if you still have the same issue after checking the above steps.